# mongoose.connect() is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to connect to my MongoDB using Mongoose and it gives me the following error.

```js
const { mongoose } = require('mongoose');

const db = 'dburl.com/db'

mongoose.connect(db, { useNewUrlParser: true })
    .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected'))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

I get this Error

```
mongoose.connect(db, { useNewUrlParser: true })
         ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change 2 things:

1. Change `{ mongoose }` with `mongoose`
2. Remove `useNewUrlParser` option. New version of Mongoose does not accept it as option and it will throw an error.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const db = 'dburl.com/db'

mongoose.connect(db)
    .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected'))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 3):

No need to destructure the mongoose in 1st line. Replace your 1st line of code with the below code. It should be work.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
```